# How to implement initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString ? why most people use allocWithZone instead of alloc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, alloc

I have a doubt about the question of "How to implement initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString".

I search many answer of this question.Most of them use allocWithZone instead of alloc,but as i know, NSZone is abandoned by apple because of some reason.
Most of people write code to implement this method like this:

```
+ (id) stringWithCString: (const char*)nullTerminatedCString 
            encoding: (NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
  NSString  *obj;
  obj = [self allocWithZone: NSDefaultMallocZone()];
  obj = [obj initWithCString: nullTerminatedCString encoding: encoding];
  return AUTORELEASE(obj);
}
```

I don't understand why they don't write like this:

```
+ (id) stringWithCString: (const char*)nullTerminatedCString 
            encoding: (NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
  NSString  *obj;
  obj = [self alloc];
  obj = [obj initWithCString: nullTerminatedCString encoding: encoding];
  return AUTORELEASE(obj);
}
```

Is there any wrong with my way, who can tell me ?

Answer (score 1):

[That method already exists as part of the SDK on NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithCString:encoding:), so I'm not sure why you would want to implement it.  Having said that, the two implementations you provide above are equivalent.  [As noted in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc), `alloc` actually invokes `allocWithZone:`.

[The documentation for `allocWithZone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/allocWithZone:) also indicates that `alloc` is probably a preferred choice.  It states:

```
This method exists for historical reasons; memory zones are no longer used by Objective-C.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. 
     The reason that why i wan't to implement it is i got a Interview question, but i really don't understand the answer of it, because all of them using `allocWithZone` instead of `alloc`, so i wan't to know why do they do this. So as your mean, i can using code like this ?
    obj = [self alloc];
    obj = [obj initWithCString: nullTerminatedCString encoding: encoding];
Is it a right way to implement this method ?

Comment: Based on the documentation I would say that calling `[self alloc]` is more correct than `[self allocWithZone:NSDefaultMallocZone()]`.  [The documentation for allocWithZone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/allocWithZone:) states "This method exists for historical reasons; memory zones are no longer used by Objective-C."